# Need expert opinion for the scenario defined below in description

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT
VP.PERSONNUM,
VP.PAYCODENAME,
VP.PAYCODEID,
VP.TIMEINSECONDS,
TI.ENTEREDONDTM,
VP.APPLYDATE,
VP.LABORLEVELNAME2,
VP.LABORLEVELNAME4,
VP.LABORLEVELNAME5,[enter image description here][1]
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),VP.ADJUSTEDAPPLYDATE,23) ORIGINALDATE,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),VP.PREVPAYPERIODSTART,23)PREVPAYPERIODSTAR,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),VP.PREVPAYPERIODEND,112)PREVPAYPERIODEND

FROM VP_TOTALS VP
JOIN TIMESHEETITEM TI
ON TI.EMPLOYEEID = VP.EMPLOYEEID AND TI.TIMESHEETITEMID = VP.TIMESHEETITEMID and TI.DELETEDSW <> '1' 
WHERE VP.PAYCODETYPE <> 'G' 
and VP.PERSONNUM='100419'
and vp.PAYCODEID in ('145','701')
AND APPLYDATE BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30'
Order by VP.PERSONNUM, VP.APPLYDATE
```

have 2 pay codes Overtime(SWG)Regular(SWG) coming separately in individual rows based on the dates
Example- 1st row personnum =100149 , applydate =6/3/2020, paycode =Overtime(SWG),Timeinseconds =1800
2nd row personnum is 100149 , applydate =6/3/2020, paycode Regular(SWG),Timeinseconds =1500.
2)My main requirement is these two rows should be added together and show only 1 row by adding together.
i.e.personnum =100149 , applydate =6/3/2020, paycode = [Overtime(SWG)+Regular(SWG)] ,Timeinseconds =2300][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUbwX.png)

Comment: You haven't asked any kind of question here. What are you asking? Why doesn't what you have work? Have is that mess of text at the end? Why tag 2 unsupported versions of SQL Server, one that is completely unsupported?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what all is going on with the WHERE conditions.  Based on what's described in the notes I'm thinking something like this.

[Edit] Added PAYCODEID concatenation to the GROUP BY clause

```
;with
overtime_cte as (select * from VP_TOTALS where PAYCODEID='Overtime(SWG)' and VP.PERSONNUM='100419'),
regular_cte as (select * from VP_TOTALS where PAYCODEID='Regular(SWG)' and VP.PERSONNUM='100419')
select rc.PERSONNUM, rc.APPLYDATE, concat(rc.PAYCODEID, '+', oc.PAYCODEID) PAYCODEID,
       sum(rc.TIMEINSECONDS+oc.TIMEINSECONDS)
from regular_cte rc
     join
     overtime_cte oc on rc.PERSONNUM=oc.PERSONNUM
                        and rc.APPLYDATE=oc.APPLYDATE
group by rc.PERSONNUM, rc.APPLYDATE, concat(rc.PAYCODEID, '+', oc.PAYCODEID);
```